# Convert Google Sheet date to its number format before importing to Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I needed a script that will delete rows from a Google sheet if their timestamp goes past the inactivity date, which is 31 days past from today's date. I found a script that could do this and just modified it a little to fit my needs. It didn't work. I spent 30 minutes trying to figure out what isn't working and finally realized through logs, that when Apps Script pulls the date from the sheet, it pulls this:

> Mon Aug 24 06:33:33 GMT+01:00 2020

instead of the number format of dates for Google Sheet. I need a way to convert that date to the number format. This is the script that I was working on:

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('RAW - Roll Call');
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var today = Date.now()/86400000 + 25569;
  var inactivityDate = today-31;
  for (var i = values.length - 1; i >= 0;  i--) {
    if (values[i][0] < inactivityDate) {
      sheet.deleteRow(i+1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your sheet?

Comment: I don't know how to mark a question as closed but I've already taken care of it with the help from Krzysztof's answer. Converting it into the timestamp that Javascript uses meant that I could then convert that timestamp to the date system that Google Sheet uses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty simple problem, taking into account that the `Date` constructor already supports most of the common date formats.

Converting your date to the timestamp is as simple as passing it as an argument to it.

```
function dateToTimestamp(date) {
  return new Date(date).getTime();
}

dateToTimestamp("Mon Aug 24 06:33:33 GMT+01:00 2020")
```

It will return a timestamp of `1598247213000`

Comment: Google Sheet uses the 1900 date system, wherein if you input the number 1 into a cell and change its format into a Date format, it will display 12/31/1899. This is the conversion I was talking about. Converting the date into this integer/number format the Google Sheet uses, and not an actual timestamp haha

Comment: Nevermind, I'm an idiot lol. I converted the dates to timestamps just like you said, converted them to days and added 25569 to convert them to the date system Google was using. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

If the Date column in the Google Sheet is of type Date, the getValues() method will return the column value as date object.

```
function deleteRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('RAW - Roll Call');
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var today = new Date();
  var today = Date.now()/86400000 + 25569;
  var inactivityDate = today-31;
  for (var i = values.length - 1; i >= 0;  i--) {
    var diffInDays = (today - values[i][0])/(1000*60*60*24);
    if (diffInDays < 31) {
      sheet.deleteRow(i+1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried this script and it deletes every row instead :/